DISA STIG drive partitioning (LVMs) during install of Ubuntu 24.04?
I would like to install Ubuntu 24.04 on a new (physical) system and comply with the DISA STIG for drive partitioning and secure LVM mounts. That means 'noexec' for /var and /tmp. I don't see any way in Ubuntu 24.04 to create LVMs for /var, /var/log, /var/log/audit, /tmp, etc...
I tried creating all of the LVMs manually, but the LVMs do not show up in the Ubuntu 24.04 installer. I've done this many times with RedHat but I don't see a way to do it in Ubuntu 24.04.
How do you install Ubuntu 24.04 to DISA STIG compliant LVM volumes?

I did try manually partitioning the drive, just like I used to do in 22.04 but it does not appear that 24.04 can see the LVMs like 22.04 used to do.  I am very familiar with the process to create LVMs and I have done it many times for Red Hat and Ubuntu 22.04.
The separate partitions oddly enough are not mentioned in the Ubuntu STIG but they are in the RHEL STIG.  If you load up the STIG viewer and open the RHEL STIG, search for 'noexec' and you'll see the separate partition requirement.

I don't know if I'm allowed to post screenshot links but I was able to create the LVMs with no problems.  Unfortunately they do not show up in the installer.  It looks like Ubuntu forgot to support custom LVMs.
Link to screenshot on Imgur

Side note -- The Ubuntu Server 24.04 installer does see the LVMs and lets me use them but does not install the gui but installing the Gnome desktop afterwards failed miserably for me last night.

@ThomasWard - I think you are misunderstanding what I'm saying.  I completely understand LVMs and how the work and how they are displayed.  All I'm saying is that I don't see a way to install to an LVM in Ubuntu 24.04.  This was possible in Ubuntu 22.04.
If you look at this screenshot from Ubuntu 22.04, you can see that Ubuntu 22.04 does show me the available LVMs that I manually created.  Ubuntu 24.04 does not. :(

I dug deeper in this iand you're right. But this is a side effect of the new Desktop installer.  It was not designed, I believe, with DISA STIG adherence.  This may be where you have to use a custom "automated installation" script to set things up.  This is a limitation of the installer (and always has been)

That sinks. In 22.04 (see my screenshot) we could at least select the LVM, with 24.04, we can't even see the LVMs. :(
Workaround....  I used Ubuntu Server 24.04 which does support LVMs and then installed the ubuntu-gnome-destop.  It was still kind of wonky, but I fixed the minor issues that I saw pop-up.

this is a known bug by the way - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop-provision/+bug/2058511 - I'm poking to get the severity raised if possible

As of my writing on April 29, 2024, this feature is missing from the installer. However, the team is aware of it - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop-provision/+bug/2058511 details the bug on this.
During the 24.04 development cycle a brand new installer was designed around a different framework, and during that cycle the teams tried hard to get feature parity.  However not all features were fully included in the installer in time for release.  This is still on their plate, and I already poked my Desktop Team contacts about this.
The workarounds would be to either install Server and then install the corresponding desktop packageset, etc. on top of that, or create an automatic installation script that the installer can reference and use to set up the partitions.
There is no fix date yet for this on 24.04 installer ISOs.

I'm not familiar with DISA STIG requirement. However, I have successfully installed Ubuntu 24.04 desktop using LVM on my laptop.
Workaround I use

Install Ubuntu 24.04 server to the LVM partition you want
Create a simple autoinstall.yml

autoinstall:
  version: 1
  interactive-sections:
    - identity
    - locale
    - keyboard
  source:
    search_drivers: true
  storage:
    version: 1
    config:
      < copy from /var/log/installer/autoinstall-user-data >


Boot into Ubuntu 24.04 desktop installer and choose "Try ubuntu" when asked "What would you like to do with Ubuntu?"
Put the autoinstall.yml file on the live system home folder
Open terminal and run python3 -m http.server on the home folder
Open the Ubuntu installer app and select "Automated installation" when asked "How would you like to install Ubuntu?"
Use http://localhost:8000/autoinstall.yml for the autoinstall.yml URL

References:

https://canonical-subiquity.readthedocs-hosted.com/en/latest/reference/autoinstall-reference.html
https://canonical-subiquity.readthedocs-hosted.com/en/latest/tutorial/creating-autoinstall-configuration.html

